# Integrate sidebar with Python generated Leaflet map?

Tags: python, leaflet, html, folium

I have this map: [link](https://dersuchendee.github.io/openaccessprova/index.html)

It was generated through Python code, not via JS directly. I want to add the Leaflet sidebar plugin within it, but it doesn't seem to work. As you can see in the github repo [here](https://github.com/dersuchendee/openaccessprova), I followed the instructions, but the sidebar doesn't even seem to open. I feel this is because I used Python and not JS in the first place, thus the names of the variables are now different from those than the sidebar.

The original HTML file I got from Python was:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>    
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

            <script>
                L_NO_TOUCH = false;
                L_DISABLE_3D = false;
            </script>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/python-visualization/folium/master/folium/templates/leaflet.awesome.rotate.css"/>
        <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
        <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>

                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                    initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                <style>
                    #map_b7061ac807554938973c46c19ecd9206 {
                        position: relative;
                        width: 100.0%;
                        height: 100.0%;
                        left: 0.0%;
                        top: 0.0%;
                    }
                </style>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.fullscreen/1.4.2/Control.FullScreen.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.fullscreen/1.4.2/Control.FullScreen.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.1.0/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.1.0/MarkerCluster.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.1.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css"/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>    

                <div class="folium-map" id="map_b7061ac807554938973c46c19ecd9206" ></div>

    </body>
```

And the script of the map after the body. To make the sidebar, I added the links to stylesheets and scripts, downloaded those that were necessary and added in the script of the map, at the end, as the [documentation](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2/blob/master/doc/usage.md) stated:

```
 var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar').addTo(map);
```

I have tried everything, but I don't know anything about JS and something is clearly missing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem in your code is that you mixed up Leaflet version and OpenLayers version of `sidebar-v2` plugin https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2. Documentation you are referring to has only example for OpenLayers, but not for Leaflet. Have a look at Leaflet example https://turbo87.github.io/sidebar-v2/examples/index.html.

You have to remove references to OpenLayers libraries (which do not work anyway) and to OpenLayers version of `sidebar-v2` plugin (which are plenty and all over the place):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Turbo87/sidebar-v2@v0.4.0/css/ol3-sidebar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v5.3.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol3-sidebar.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v5.3.2/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="ol3-sidebar.js"></script>
```

And then add links for `sidebar-v2` Leaflet plugin (previously downloaded to your server):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-sidebar.css">
<script src="leaflet-sidebar.js"></script>
```